# Print symfony Validation class -nice string

Tags: validation, symfony

```
reg = new RegValidator($reg);

$errors = $this->validator()->validate($reg);




if (count($errors) > 0) {
            $errorsString = (string) $errors;

            throw new HttpException(521,$errorsString );
        }
```

the result is:

"Object(NameSpace\Bundle\Validator\RegValidator).email:\n    This value should not be blank.\n

but I would like to show
email : this value should not be blank
and if i have more then one so with "," between them

Answer (score 0):

You have a `ConstraintViolationList` as the result of `$this->validator()->validate($reg);`. So you can format your string in a way you want.

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $errorStrings = '';
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $errorStrings[] = sprintf("%s: %s\n", $error->getPropertyPath(), $error->getMessage());
    }
    $errorString = implode(', ', $errorStrings);
    throw new HttpException(521, $errorsString);
}
```